# What is a determinant in matrix ? NOT how to get it but WHAT is it in real life

Tags: matrix-calculus

We know to get determinant in a matrix we use sarrus, laplace, x methods and so on

But question : WHAT is it, according to some pages is about permutations the products of element of the matrix , but WHAT IS IT ?

Comment: It is a single number that can tell you much about your matrix.

Comment: 3blue1brown explains his take on the determinant in [video 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk) of his linear algebra series. I don't remember off the top of my head whether you need to see the preceeding 5, although if you have an hour to spare I do recommend you do that anyways. It conveys some pretty healthy ways to think about the basics of the subject.

Comment: You'll likely be interested in the interpretation of a matrix determinant as the *signed hyper-volume* of a parallelopiped as described in the Answers to the proposed duplicate.  That is closely related to the Jacobian appearing in multivariate change-of-variable integration formulas.  But the determinant has many applications.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} ax+by \\ cx+dy \end{array} \right] \\[8pt]
& \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} a \\ c \end{array} \right] \\[8pt]
& \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} b \\ d \end{array} \right]
\end{align}

Draw the arrows representing $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right].$ From the head of the arrow $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right],$ draw another arrow parallel to $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$ and from the head of the arrow $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$ draw another parallel to $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right].$ There you have a square whose area is $1.$

Then do the same with $\left[ \begin{array}{c} a \\ c \end{array} \right]$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{c} b \\ d \end{array} \right]$ and get a parallelogram. The area of that parallelogram is $\left|\det\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\right|.$ The determinant is positive if turning from $\left[ \begin{array}{c} a \\ c \end{array} \right]$ to $\left[ \begin{array}{c} b \\ d \end{array} \right]$ amounts to turning counterclockwise, and negative if clockwise. In other words, positive if the parallelogram has the same orientation as the square, and negative if the orientation is reversed.